# reset a char *array[size] contents

Tags: c, arrays

Say I have declared char *array[size] in my program and put some strings in it. If I assign something again to them, they don't replace the previous contents but they keep on appending on the previous contents. How do I correctly clear/reset all of its contents?

```
void function(char* action)
{
   const int myMainArrSize = 3;
   char *myMainArr[myArrSize];

   char *myArrOne[] = {"String 1", "String 2", "String 3"};
   char *myArrTwo[] = {"Another String 1", "Another String 2", "Another String 3"};

   if(strcmp(action, "action1")==0)
   {
      for(int i=0;i<myMainArrSize;i++)
      {
         myMainArr[i] = myArrOne[i];
      }
   }

   if (strcmp(action, "action2")==0)
   {
      for(int i=0;i<myMainArrSize;i++)
      {
         myMainArr[i] = myArrOne[i];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If this is C++, why not use `std::string`? Then `s.clear();`.

Comment: i'll give you an idea .. why don't you use two arrays one to changable an the other for reseting..

Comment: I'm retagging as C. Jj: that depends a lot on how you're putting data in the first time. Can you post that code?

Comment: Could you post code?  I'm curious how you could be appending to an array (or to `char*` strings, depending on what you mean) in either C or C++.

Comment: @jjj: You're not the same person as jj… confusing…

Comment: @ Potatoswatter
O_o no... i am not!!

Comment: Given your function `function` to set the array `array`, I don't see any reassigning happening.  Maybe you forgot to reassign your pointers?  Please don't name your array you're reassigning to `reassign` :-)

Comment: Code shown won't compile because you define myMainArrSize but use myArrSize.   This is probably trivially fixable.  Your code also always copies from myArrOne - should the second loop copy from myArrTwo?

Answer (score 5):

You have

```
char *array[size];
```

That makes `array` an array of pointers.  Specifically, `array` is an array of `size` pointers.  Each element in the array (`array[0]` to `array[size-1]`) is of type `char *`.

I think it would help if you understood how `array` works:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  [0]  |  [1]  |  [2]  |  [3]  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |       |       |       |
    |       |       |       |
    |       |       |       |
    v       v       v       v
```

Each of the boxes above represents a pointer, and the arrows are where they are pointing to.  The storage for them is not yet assigned to, so they are just "out there", pointing nowhere useful.  You can either create memory for them (`malloc()` etc., in C, `new[]` in C++), or you can point them to some existing location.

You say:

> ...put some strings in it. If I assign something again to them, they don't replace the previous contents but they keep on appending on the previous contents. How do I correctly clear/reset all of its contents?

It is not clear how you are putting "strings in it".  Do you mean you are storing strings in `array[0]`..`array[size-1]`?  How?  Are you assigning literal strings to them?  Something like:

```
array[0] = "String";
```

If you are doing that, then, you can reassign to the pointers and the strings wouldn't append.  In other words, if later in your program you do:

```
array[0] = "Another string";
```

you are reassigning the pointer `array[0]` to point to `"Another string"`, and thus you're not appending.

So, in short, we need to see more code, and you may need to understand pointers and arrays better.

*Edit*: Based upon your edit, the pointers `myMainArr[i]` (for `i=0` to `i=3`), *do* get reassigned to the corresponding elements from `myArrOne` or `myArrOne` (not a typo!), depending upon the contents of `action`.  So, if you printed them (for example, `printf("%s\n", myMainArr[0]);`), you shouldn't see any strings being appended.  Also, `myMainArr` is local to your function `function`, so it gets destroyed when your function returns.  (Incidentally, your choice of the names `array` for an array and `function` for a function make it harder to be unambiguous when answering the question!)

If you are having a problem, please post a *complete*, *minimal*, *compilable* code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
memset(arr, '\0', size)
```

or nul-terminate the strings when you write to arr:

```
int n = min(strlen(str, size - 1));
strncpy(arr, str, n);
arr[n] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you increment that pointer and keep writing there. You must save the pointer to the array's beginning somewhere, and when you want to reset your char array, you should zero its contents (using a call like `memset(array, 0, size)`) with that pointer, and then start writing back there.

Answer (score 0):

If new strings get appended to the contents of the array or overwrite it depends on the functions you use to add the data. For example `strcat()` appends while `strcpy()` overwrites.

If you just want to "truncate" the string to zero length it is enough to set the first character to 0:

```
array[0] = '\0';
```